# How to change pip3 command to be pip? For WIndows

Tags: pip

When I type pip I want pip3 to work in Windows commandline. Currently pip is not found and when I look in c:\python\scripts\ I see pip3.

Answer (score 0):

it seems the default version is pip on windows.
you'd better uninstall pip3 and install pip